# Add encoder.categores_ as column name in Pandas dataframe after using OneHotEncoder

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

I am using the Titanic dataset. I have done oneHotEncoding on 3 categories survived,sex,cabin.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto',
                   drop='first', 
                   sparse=False,
                   handle_unknown='error')
encoder.fit(X_train.fillna('Missing'))

tmp = encoder.transform(X_train.fillna('Missing'))

onepd = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns= encoder.categories_)
```

The ecoder.categories_ array size is not same tmp. Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

encoder.categories_ is a matrix maybe, try index first element:

Try this:

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto',
                   drop='first', 
                   sparse=False,
                   handle_unknown='error')
encoder.fit(X_train.fillna('Missing'))

tmp = encoder.transform(X_train.fillna('Missing'))

onepd = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns= encoder.categories_[0])
```